# Magento 1.7 : Import large number of configurable products using CSV

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am working on project in which I need to create large number of configurable products. 
I have two option either

> > **1.** I manually create configurable product and associated simple products to it
> >
> > **2.** Pragmatically import product CSV.

If I create product manually it takes too much time to create a single product. Please help me how do I import configurable product CSV. I have read **MAGMI** but its working fine with simple product but I don't know how do I use it with configurable products because there no sample CSV for it. Can anyone suggest me something good to import configurable product pragmatically ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI sanchit for this purpose first upload all simple Products using magmi or the way you import and for configurable here is csv file .

```
sku,type,product_type_id,configurable_attributes,Google_upc,attribute_set,cpack_qty,simple_skus,name,
720825393483,configurable,configurable,size,720825393483,Default,1,"720825393483-xs,720825393483-s,720825393483-m,720825393483-l,720825393483-xl,720825393483-2xl",Love Equals No Labels - Ladies White T-Shirt,Love Equals No Labels - Ladies White T-Shirt,Love Equals No Labels - Ladies White T-Shirt,Love Equals No Labels - Ladies White T-Shirt,
```

And for associate product you can add column `simple_skus` for this provide Comma seprated simple_skus for this column , and in `type` column as `configurable` for all row, and also follow below example

[image]

Comment: Thank you @murtuza, Please let me know if is it possible that I can create simple products and assign them to configurable products using single CSV and execute the file only once.

Comment: It would be great if you provide me sample CSV.

Comment: Yes it is possible first upload all simple product and upload all configurable product shown in my answer you can give comma seprated skus for `simple_skus` column in csv and on the setting for magmi as shown in image

Comment: Do I need some extra plugins require to import configurable products with **MAGMI** as I read in the magmi documentation ?

Comment: No this all were provided By default

Comment: Happy Coding :)